# how to write code to find element in directory in Linq

Tags: linq, loops

How to search for each file in a single directory of xml files and get value of one element?

I tried to loop in Linq:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(C:\Users\valen\Downloads\2019-11-04 apmt, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files) {
    var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
```

I need to find shipment element in <>.

Comment: It would be great if you could share your XML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to help when there is very little information about your XML given in OP. Assuming you are searching for Element `ShipmentId` in your xml files, you could search the Xml File using Linq. For example,

```
var listOfShipmentIds = new List<string>();
var files = Directory.GetFiles(folderToSearch, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach(var file in files)
{
        var dataRead = XDocument.Load(file)
                            .Root
                            .DescendantNodes()
                            .OfType<XElement>()
                            .Where(x=>x.Name.LocalName.Equals("ShipmentId"))
                            .Select(x=>x.Value);
        listOfShipmentIds.AddRange(dataRead);
}
```

This would enable you to parse the Xml files and get the value of Element specified.

Comment: @ValentinaBishay Glad to help you. Kindly marked it answer/useful if it helped you resolve the issue